# Check if value exists in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, data-structures

I am trying to check if a value is present in a nested array. This is what the data I am working with looks like:

```
[
    {
      name: 'bob',
      occupation: ['Teacher', 'Store Owner'],
    },
    {
      name: 'grace',
      occupation: ['Doctor'],
    },
]
```

I am trying to see if the occupation value already exists. This is my current code:

```
const occupationExists = (value) => users.some((user) => user.occupation === value);
```

I understand that this doesn't work because it isn't accessing the values in the array but how do I go about it? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check `occupation` as well with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
const occupationExists = value => users.some(user =>
    user.occupation.includes(value)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, it returns true/false depending on whether the occupation exists or not.

```
let users = [
    {
      name: 'bob',
      occupation: ['Teacher', 'Store Owner'],
    },
    {
      name: 'grace',
      occupation: ['Doctor'],
    },
]


const occupationExists = (value) => {
    let res = users.filter((user) =>
        user.occupation.indexOf(value) != -1
    )
    return res.length > 0
}
let value = 'Doctor'
console.log(occupationExists(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue with `user.occupation === value`: `user.occupation` is an array of string while `value` is a string, hence you cannot compare the two. You can use `Array#includes()` as stated by @NinaScholz or you can use another (inner) `Array#some()` and within it you can compare string to string: `job === value`.

```js
const users = [{name: 'bob',occupation: ['Teacher', 'Store Owner']}, {name: 'grace',occupation: ['Doctor']}];

//const occupationExists = value => users.some(user => user.occupation.includes(value)); //best answer

//Alternative answer
const occupationExists = value => users.some(
    user => user.occupation.some(job => job === value)
);

console.log( occupationExists('Teacher') );
console.log( occupationExists('Developer') );
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let aoo = [
    {
      name: 'bob',
      occupation: ['Teacher', 'Store Owner'],
    },
    {
      name: 'grace',
      occupation: ['Doctor', 'Store Owner'],
    },
]

let fullOccupation = []

aoo.map(obj => {
  obj.occupation.map(occ => {
    const check = fullOccupation.includes(occ) 
          console.log(occ)
          if(!check)
          {
            fullOccupation.push(occ)
          }else{
                    alert(occ)

          }
  })
})
```

Comment: Why are you using `map` and not `filter`? And `map` returns an array, so why are you treating it like a `for/loop`?

Comment: Its just an another way of solution

Comment: That's not how `map` should be used.

Comment: Is it documented some where.

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)